# Reloading a Mediaelement audio player

Tags: shortcode, audio

I am writing a WordPress plugin *(private and not intended to be publicly available)* in which I am displaying a huge list of audio files *(about a thousand)* along with **ONE** audio player *(like the one created by the [audio] shortcode)*, initially hidden and filled by a dummy audio file.

The idea is that when I select any audio file inside the page, I use javascript *(with jQuery)* to dynamically replace the current *(initially dummy)* audio file contained inside the player, move the player near the selected audio file link and make it visible.

This works quite well, and I succeed that way in managing a quite flexible method to quickly access all audio files in my page.

The only problem that I have is when I do that while a previous audio file is already playing: in that case, the player switches to a quite stalling state, and I have to stop and restart it manually in order to play the new file. It still works of course, but this is not very beautiful.

So I am looking for a way to locate the existing *mediaelement* player *(by javascript)* in order to apply a stop and reset command to it before *(or while)* loading the new file.

Please could somebody helps me on that problem?

Gingko

Comment: Have you looked at the [MediaElement documentation](https://github.com/mediaelement/mediaelement/blob/master/docs/api.md#methods)? It looks like you probably want a combination of the methods `setSrc` and `load`.

Comment: Yes I did. Of course I may want to use a combination of `setSrc` and `load` but what I am not able to find actually in this documentation is how to locate the existing object instance on which to apply the `setSrc` and `load` methods … especially into the WordPress implementation of it.